# Turning React Native Inputs Required like on Html

Tags: react-native

REACT NATIVE

I'm designing an App and I was wondering if it was possible to turn my text and password inputs required, so my clients can't click Login button without filling all the requiring fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a textField in react native required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665162/how-can-i-make-a-textfield-in-react-native-required)

Comment: Look like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51665162/how-can-i-make-a-textfield-in-react-native-required , also maybe this help too: https://medium.com/@pavsidhu/validating-forms-in-react-native-7adc625c49cf . There doesn't seem to be an easy way like in HTML (required attribute). You have to code it yourself.